# How to merge values from one array into another one?

Tags: php

I have two arrays and need to join or merge them into one.

```
        $array1 = array(
            array("Account 1", "EUR", "100", "333"),
            array("Account 2", "EUR", "200", "444")
            );

        $array2 = array(
            array("Account 1", "EUR", "100", "111"),
            array("Account 2", "EUR", "200", "222")
            );

        $array = array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

Then my outcome is:

```
[["Account 1","EUR","100","333"],["Account 2","EUR","200","444"],["Account 1","EUR","100","111"],["Account 2","EUR","200","222"]]
```

I would like to have like this:

```
[["Account 1","EUR","100","333","111"],["Account 2","EUR","200","444","222"]]
```

How to make it? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, SO is not a code writing service, you have to come here with something you have coded on your own, that we may help you to improve if required.

Comment: I added my code and edited my question.

Comment: there's not php function to automatically merge the arrays the way you want, you will have to code it yourself with loop(s).

Comment: I got stuck with that. Could you give me some more advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the program should append the last element of array2[i] to array1[i]. You'll need a loop of course, and you may find [PHP: end](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) helpful. If that is *not* the intent of the program, then be sure to update the question with a more accurate problem statement or example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the problem:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
  $array1[$i][]=$array2[$i][3];
}
```